# Display or save a List of URL images

Tags: python

Python is known to be an easy and powerful language. I have a List, literally, of URL images,

```
>>> for i in images: print i

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Influenza_virus_research.jpg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Wiktionary-logo-en.svg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e7/Cscr-featured.svg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Wikiquote-logo.svg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Wikisource-logo.svg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Wikiversity-logo-en.svg
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Wikiversity-logo-en.svg
```

I wonder if there's some library (or snippet of code) in python to easily display a list of URL images in a browser, or maybe save them in a folder.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to fetch all the images from a certain webpage and save them somewhere?

Comment: hey! I know my question is somewhat newbie, but is it so wrong to vote it down?

Comment: Your question is not downvoted because it is easy to answer, but because it is too broad to be answered. You have to give more details because what you actually want is not clear.

Comment: I mean a List, literally. I have a Python list with URL images. I want to display them in a browser (within a tab), or just save them to a folder in my hard drive.

Comment: Do you want to download images and save the images or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Then this is what you should have said in your post. A question like yours should always include what you already have, and what you want to do with what you have. You should also provide code, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've updated my question providing my 'images' list output. I made that simple question because it should be an easy way on Python.

Comment: It's not a matter of something being easy or not. When we __do not understand__ what you want to do, it is __not possible__ to give an appropriate answer. It is clear from the answers that were given to you that nobody actually understood what you wanted before you edited your post.

Comment: The code in my answer saves the images to any folder you specify, if you already have the images I am still a bit unclear as to what you want to do with them.

Comment: Great way to be a learner and improve your question @autorun!  Few new users actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://8020.photos.jpgmag.com/3670771_314453_2ee7120da5_m.jpg",   "my.jpg")
```

The "my.jpg" is the path to save the file. It can be "/home/user/pics/my.jpg" etc..